# Identifying training sites?

Tags: classification, imagery

Prior to image classification, collection of training sites and obtaining a signature file is the most critical step. Field visits with a reliable GPS Unit is usually the first step followed by overlaying the points on the to-be-classified image. Other than this when identifying training sites on satellite images, especially the coarse resolution ones what are the rules normally followed by professionals - like minimum number of pixels in a training site, distance between two training sites for same/different classes, how improvements are made after preliminary classification etc. Standard references are also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wont be able to give a great deal of information on this, but there are certain rules I think we need to follow for training sites:

- Training sites should be spread all over the image i.e. should be covering a large area and not just focussed in a region
- Just as Georeferencing, training sites should be identified at the corners and at points which give maximum sampling options
- The objective is to identify a set of
  pixels that accurately represents spectral variation present within each
  information region

Answer (score 2):

The article below highlights some concepts regarding number of pixels per training site, and number of training sites per class for sampling (pg 2).  [Hawth's tools](http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/tooldesc.php)  can be used to generate random stratified training points if you are using ArcGIS.

[Improving image classification accuracy: a method to incorporate uncertainty in the selection of training sample sets](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255908408_Improving_image_classification_accuracy_a_method_to_incorporate_uncertainty_in_the_selection_of_training_sample_sets)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly a little more detail about your application would help return a better answer.
Second, generally speaking in natural systems it is rare to find linear relationships and so you cannot rely on having two points make a line. You need more. But most importantly you need points "in the middle". If you are lucky the relationship between the remote sensing output and the feature of interest will be a modest curve and the midpoint of that curve will be easier to define if you have some or many points near the middle.

With regard professionals... I say that all they know is how to cut the corners, so don't do what they do! Use best practice and find a suitable statistical test which tells you when you have gathered enough data. Plotting stuff up on the fly is a good start.